# D3 Collapsible tree implementation in OBIEE

Tags: d3.js

Could you please help me in implementing Collapsible Tree example in OBIEE. Something like this

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

Thanks in anticipation.

Regards,
Mohammad Rafi Ansari

Answer (score 0):

we can embed the D3.js in OBIEE and call the script using the Narrative view. Also, Rittman Mead has created the plugin pack for OBIEE using D3.js it's an open source, I am not sure this Tree visualization is a part of the package.

please have a look below URL

https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/the-visual-plugin-pack-for-obiee/

Comment: Thanks Avinash for the reply. Yes. I saw that. But I am looking some help just for implementing Collapsible Tree example in OBIEE. Something like this

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd